# RUBY ON RAILS-Get user input to insert into database,process it, insert new variable into database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, insert

User is required to input a name (that will insert into database) and I need the user input name to use in another function to process then I need the newly processed input to insert into database.

So far, i manage to do is:

```
 A name inserted into database
 -> I saved it (name = personname, nameJob = nil)
 -> I update_attribute('nameJob', nameJob_func(params[:name]))
```

Is there a better way where I can insert both entries together into the database after I process the nameJob_func()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ca[n create a `before_save` callback](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) which performs the `nameJob_func()` function. You therefore never need to call it explicitly, as Rails will call it just before the object is saved.  Only the input name needs to be dealt with.

```
YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Register nameJob_func as a callback
  before_save :nameJob_func

private
  def nameJob_func
    # Do something with self.name
    self.nameJob = 'something you made here with #{self.name}'
    # This value will get saved to the database automatically
  end
end
```

Now, whenever the object calls `.save()`, `nameJob_func()` runs and gets its updated value from `:name`.

```
YourModelsController < ActionController::Base
  def create
    @yourobj = YourModel.new(params[:name])
    # The callback is called and then the whole thing gets saved
    @yourobj.save
  end
end
```

Comment: It report "wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)" in myModel.rb

Comment: @AmySukumunu The nameJob_func used as before_save should have no parameter since it doesn't need them -- it only needs `self.name`. If that doesn't help, post the full error.